# How do I run XPlanner+?

Tags: war, extreme-programming

I've installed XPLanner+ from its website.
The downloaded file is called: "xplanner-plus.war"

I've extracted this file using 7-zip software.

I get these file names in the folder "xplanner-plus":

- editTimeEntries.js
- form.js
- index.jsp
- overlib.js
- time.js
- toggle.js

In addition of multiple folders containing lots of other files; folders names:

- calendar
- css
- files
- images
- js
- META-INF
- WEB-INF

I have no Idea of how do I open the xplanner+ !!!!

Please some help :(

Comment: This is a web application. You can't run a web application on your desktop. The system requirements even say what application server and database to use.

Comment: Thank you @Luminous for your reply. Sorry for this dum question ... I am totally novice to web application :( Does it need internet running on my computer to launch it?

Comment: No. You do need to have a server to run it on though.

Comment: Thanks again. One more question. I have Apache server. Can it run XPLanner+? and how do I ran it?

Comment: Sorry, one more note: I have insatlled Xampp earlier, so I have Tomcat. but i have no idea how to run XPlanner+! especially that there is no html page in its folder! .... Please some help.

Comment: I don't know. Figure it out. Go find and read the instructions. Make mistakes. Don't be so helpless.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need any webserver. 
We used tomact server for this. Start tomcat server and then deploy the war file. Once deployed,

use the below URL:

http://[IP_ADDRESS]:[PORTNO]/xplanner-plus

for ex: http://localhost:8080/xplanner-plus